# (HEROKU) Error R10 (Boot timeout). App crash, How to solve?

Tags: heroku, crash

I have a problem when trying to run my application (discord bot). It works for few minutes, but when I try to run some commands the app crash.

Github: `https://github.com/Emivg/Pepe-Assistant`

Log: `https://pastebin.com/n5n36NS0`

Thanks for read, hope someone could help me with this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions on Stack Overflow should be self-contained. We're not going to go off-site to dig through your code ourselves. Please read [ask], then come back and [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for adding your own answer. I've rolled back your question to its previous state. Solutions don't belong in questions.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I added a Procfile with:

```
worker: npm start
heroku ps:scale web=0
```